# TFS Shelving - How to work on same file after shelving my changes

Tags: tfs

I have shelved my changes in TFS which will be checked-in in two weeks time. Now i need to work on separate TFS card which belongs to same file i shelved earlier.

How can i work on the file which has changes in shelve set.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you should be using branches, not shelving. Shelving is intended for short-term suspension of work in progress.

That said, when you create a shelveset, you can either choose to keep the changes checked out, or to restore the files to their original state. You chose to keep the files checked out. You can undo the changes to your workspace and then continue to work. You can unshelve your shelved changes later.

But seriously, use branches for this.